# Wordpress blank front blank page not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress for cpanel via Softaculous app installer' that i installed theme. Theme is working properly after one day my font page not working.

This is error long.

```
[29-Apr-2018 07:56:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/eco/public_html/wp-includes/post.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
[29-Apr-2018 07:56:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/eco/public_html/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
[29-Apr-2018 07:57:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/eco/public_html/wp-includes/post.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
[29-Apr-2018 07:57:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/eco/public_html/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166
[30-Apr-2018 02:09:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/eco/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vangard/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 426
[30-Apr-2018 02:09:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/eco/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vangard/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 426
[30-Apr-2018 02:09:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/eco/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vangard/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 426
[30-Apr-2018 02:09:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/eco/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vangard/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/eco/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 426
[30-Apr-2018 02:09:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FT_scope' not found in /home/eco/public_html/wp-content/themes/Vangard/header.php on line 28
```

Would you tell me how to fix it. thanks

Comment: It says `Permission denied`, so change permissions.

Comment: whic files i have to change permissions ?

Comment: read your error log...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the error is because of a file permission issue. 
If this is a local setup on your own system then simply right click on the wordpress installation (root project folder) and set them to 755
or set owner with **all permissions** and the rest with only **access files**

apply this recursively to all folders

Answer (score 0):

you have incorrect permissions / file ownership on your project.

the best and easiest way to do it by using the following:

```
$ sudo find /path/to/site -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
$ sudo find /path/to/site -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

this will find everything in site root that is a file and set permissions to 644, then it will find everything that a directory and set it to 755.

if the permissions error returns after that, check root isn't the owner (by running `ls -la` on your directory to bring up the files in list view with file permissions and owners). If this is the case, set it to your home user or apache:

```
$ sudo chown -R /path/to/site my-user:www-data
```